# How to get WFS GetCapabilities information as JSON

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, file-formats, getcapabilities

I can get a WMS GetCapabilities response via AJAX call and I can convert response to JSON using [ol.format.WMSCapabilities](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.WMSCapabilities.html) tool.

But I need to make a WFS GetCapabilities query via a AJAX request and get  a JSON result.

How can I do it?

My GetCapabilities operation metadata is like this:

[image]

Comment: What does not work with the explanation in the manual? http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

Comment: That document page is about WFS and GetFeature response, not about  GetCapabilities.

Answer (score 4):

For versions of the WFS interface standard prior to version 2.0, the only format supported as a response was XML.

From WFS version 2.0 whilst a WFS GetCapabilites defaults to XML a request can now include an `AcceptFormats` parameter which must include the `"text/xml"` value, but may include other vendor specified formats.

So you could make a request like:

`http://aWFSsever/wfs?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&AcceptFormats=application/json,text/xml&`

If the server supports WFS 2.0 it will give you a JSON response if it supports it as a GetCapabilites response format, otherwise it will give you XML.  If the server is not WFS 2.0 it will ignore the AcceptFormats parameter and give you XML.

Comment: I updated the post with an image of Operations metadata

Comment: So in this case you can only get XML from the service.

Comment: What can I do to support application/json? Installing another geoserver version or change existing geoserver settings?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible using geoserver at the moment.  That's probably a question worth asking on  the [geoserver-dev mail list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GeoServer-Dev-f3819232.html).  Otherwise, if you don't need to use WFS 2, you can try the route suggested by @bartvde

Comment: See the capabilities of http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities. The response shows `ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities" - ows:Parameter name="AcceptFormats" - ows:Value>text/xml</ows:Value`. GeoServer does not support any additional formats for GetCapabilities. You must contact (or contract) developers.

Comment: I think this is an important lack of geoserver wfs service.

Comment: @barteloma geoserver welcomes contributions to enhance the program, feel free to submit a PR, or consider funding the enhancement

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSONIX and ogc-schemas for this

```
const wfsContext = new Jsonix.Context([OWS_1_0_0, Filter_1_1_0, SMIL_2_0, SMIL_2_0_Language, XLink_1_0, GML_3_1_1, WFS_1_1_0]);
const wfsUnmarshaller = wfsContext.createUnmarshaller();

var info = wfsUnmarshaller.unmarshalDocument(xmlhttp.responseXML).value;
```

See here for more example code: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/sdk/blob/master/src/services/WFSService.js#L80

Comment: the link to the example code is dead

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can make use of this code on GitHub:

https://github.com/w8r/wms-capabilities

```
npm install wms-capabilities --save
var WMSCapabilities = require('wms-capabilities');
...
new WMSCapabilities().parse(xmlString);
//or
new WMSCapabilities(xmlString).toJSON();`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the detailed steps based on the solution suggested by @bartvde.

#### Requirements

This solution is supported by the modules `jsonix` and `ogc-schemas`.

#### Setup

```bsh
mkdir -p ~dev/jsonix
cd ~dev/jsonix
npm init
npm install jsonix
npm install ogc-schemas
```

#### Example data

Get a GetCapabilities document from a known server or from your own server, like:

```bsh
curl -o getcapabilities.xml "https://wssig4.azores.gov.pt/geoserver/ows?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&version=2.0.0"
```

You can also use the test document `node_modules/ogc-schemas/tests/WFS/2.0/GetCapabilities-01.xml` provided by `ogc-schemas`.

#### Minimal code

Write a minimal `index.js` file.

```js
var Jsonix = require('jsonix').Jsonix;

var XLink_1_0 = require('w3c-schemas').XLink_1_0;
var OWS_1_1_0 = require('ogc-schemas').OWS_1_1_0;
var WFS_2_0 = require('ogc-schemas').WFS_2_0;
var Filter_2_0 = require('ogc-schemas').Filter_2_0;

var context =  new Jsonix.Context([XLink_1_0, OWS_1_1_0, WFS_2_0, Filter_2_0]);
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

// you can use node_modules/ogc-schemas/tests/WFS/2.0/GetCapabilities-01.xml for testing
unmarshaller.unmarshalFile("getcapabilities.xml", function(result) {
    // console.log(result);
    // console.log(result.value.featureTypeList.featureType);
    result.value.featureTypeList.featureType.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
        console.log(element.name.localPart);
    });
});
```

#### Running

```bsh
node index.js | head
pooc_smg_sul_adutoras
pobhl_scd_acessosplanoagua
pobhl_fur_acessosplanoagua
pooc_gra_adutora
pooc_flo_adutora
pooc_cor_adutora
pooc_smg_norte_adutoras
pooc_pic_adutoras
pooc_ter_adutoras
pooc_fai_adutoras
```